# How can I get new public IP without rebooting in AWS EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

Generally AWS EC2 provide you a new public IP whenever you reboot your instance. But in case I want to get a new public IP without rebooting instance, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Allocating a new `Elastic IP` and Attaching it to your Instance. This will override your current Public IP.

Additionally every time you need a newer address to your same instance you can try **Allocating - Associating - Dissociating** the IPs. Elastic IPs are free for the instances which are running.

When you stop the instance you need to release the address if not you would incur cost for the idle IP.

Comment: To add to this, it's easy to allocate a new elastic ip address to a server with the aws cli. So if you have some autoscaling, you can have it allocate the specific IP you want to the new instance that starts up.